# How to refresh an ember-data collection?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

We have an index route that sets the model to a collection filtered by a property like this:

```
App.Post.find(isNew: false)
```

As expected, it automatically refreshes when records are created and destroyed. However, it does not refresh when the filtered property changes.

I think it ought to observe all filter properties for each record so that it always represents the matching collection, but maybe that doesn't make sense for performance or other reasons.

This is no problem, we can observe the properties and record(s) manually, but how do we manually refresh the collection?

Answer (score 0):

We solved this with this syntax when setting our model:

```
App.Post.find()
App.Post.filter (p) ->
  !p.get('isNew')
```